# Finding dates within one year of each other

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to determine the number of employees who left the company within 1 year of being hired:

```
SELECT 
    Min(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT) AS MinOfEMP_RHR_DT, 
    Max(O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT) AS MaxOfREC_EFF_STT_DT, 
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR
FROM O896IA_VEMPPRSA 
INNER JOIN O867IA_VJOBHST 
    ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VJOBHST.SYS_EMP_ID_NR
WHERE 
    O867IA_VJOBHST.EMP_ACN_TYP_CD="TER"
GROUP BY 
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR;
```

EMP_RHR_DT is the original hire date, and REC_EFF_STT_DT is the date they quit/were fired. Again I need the REC_EFF_STT_DT to be within 365 days of the EMP_RHR_DT. Any thoughts?

Example of RHR Date Changes. IN some cases there will only be one job but still a negative days worked, in other cases it is because it is selecting the wrong job.

```
Job     MinOfEMP_RHR_DT     MaxOfREC_EFF_STT_DT     daysworked     SYS_EMP_ID_NR
abc1     10/24/2012            4/15/2013               173           123456
abc1     4/25/2013             4/13/2013               -12           234567
abc3     7/8/2013              1/4/2013                -185          891234
abc4     7/8/2013              7/29/2013               21            891234
```

Comment: Could you provide your table structures for both tables? Do the tables have 1 to many relationship with O896IA_VEMPPRSA being the master and O867IA_VJOBHST containing detail records?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming O896IA_VEMPPRSA is master table and O867IA_VJOBHST is detail table with the following data:

```
O896IA_VEMPPRSA:
ID  EMP_RHR_DT      SYS_EMP_ID_NR   Empname
1   8/10/2012       1               John
2   10/10/2012      2               Matthew

O867IA_VJOBHST:
ID  SYS_EMP_ID_NR   EMP_ACN_TYP_CD  REC_EFF_STT_DT
1   1               Married         1/1/2003
2   1               Became dad      8/1/2003
3   1               TER             9/10/2013
5   2               Remarried       1/1/2003
6   2               Remarried       8/1/2003
7   2               TER             9/10/2013
```

You could do this to get the number of days worked:

```
SELECT 
    Min(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT) AS MinOfEMP_RHR_DT, 
    Max(O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT) AS MaxOfREC_EFF_STT_DT, 
    Max(O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT) - Min(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT) as daysworked,
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR
FROM O896IA_VEMPPRSA 
INNER JOIN O867IA_VJOBHST 
    ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VJOBHST.SYS_EMP_ID_NR
WHERE 
    O867IA_VJOBHST.EMP_ACN_TYP_CD="TER"
GROUP BY 
    O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR;
    HAVING
            (Max(O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT) - Min(O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT)) < 365;
```

Comment: This works but for some reason I am getting people who have a FIRED date that is before their HIRED date. Sometimes in the system when an employee changes jobs their RHR date changes, any ideas for a solution to get their very first one?

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide some example data of cases where RHR date was changed? Can you also post an example output you desire? That might allow the community to help you better. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry; I misspoke. I was looking to see raw data and not results from the query. Your raw data from both tables will help me understand how your data is laid out and write the appropriate SQL. Sorry for the extra work.

Comment: I normally use this code in SQL to solve this issue: (SELECT MAX(REC_EFF_STT_DT) AS Expr1
                    FROM   O867IA_VJOBHST AS A
                    WHERE (SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VJOBHST.SYS_EMP_ID_NR))) But right now it is giving an error in Access that reads, INCONSISTENT DATA TYPES: EXPECTED DATE GOT NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

The solution is with the datediff function. You will end up with a constraint like:

```
WHERE DateDiff("yyyy",hiringDate, endingDate)<1
```

Please check the exact syntax for the DateDiff function in the MS-Access help